# String comparison in TCL

Tags: scripting, tcl

I have a variable `nodename = v445` and another variable `nodepatch=v445-sctpsv`

I want to compare as

```
if { $nodename == ???????} {
 }
```

so here I just want to compare only part before certain  `-`  the second variable could contain more than one - in name, so I just want to extract equivalent string to nodename to compare with.
after string manipulation second part should come up like this:

```
if { $nodename == "v445"} {
 proceed } else { 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
set nodename v445
set nodepatch v445-sctpsv

if {[string match $nodename* $nodepatch]} {
    proceed
} else {
}
```

`string match` does a glob-style match against a string, in this case the string that starts with the value in `$nodename` and contains zero or more characters is matched against the string `$nodepatch`.

If you need to ensure that the dash occurs, use `string match $nodename-* $nodepatch` instead.

Documentation: [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)